# model access from layout file in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a CMS using CakePHP and I want to create a dynamic menu which is the same on all the pages the user can access. So I figured out to create in the layout (since it shared among so many pages and view) but I don't seem to know how to acces the model and get the data from the database to construct the menu. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because <strike>for proper MVC separation</strike>* in Cake you're not supposed to access the Model from the View. The only part with access to data should be the Controller (via the Model), which hands it down to the View, which simply displays the data.

As such, using a [`beforeFilter`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/60/Callbacks) callback in your global [`AppController`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller) to `set()` the data is probably the best choice.

In emergencies you can always access anything from anywhere by loading an instance of the needed Class using [`ClassRegistry::init`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/class-registry#method-ClassRegistryinit), but you really shouldn't.

---

* Actually, in "proper MVC" there's no problem with the View getting data directly from the model. You shouldn't do that in *templates* necessarily, but View related code can well get data from the model to visualise the model state. It just doesn't really work that way in Cake, because Cake is not proper MVC and default Cake views are only templates.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative could be [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/view/434/requestAction), it allows you to call controller actions from views/layouts, and in those actions you can then access the desired model(s).